# Redirect URL using .htaccess for woocommerce page

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect

I want to set a URL for woocommerce my account page.

The default one is *www.sitename.com/my-account*

I want a URL for eg:
www.sitename.com/page should redirect to *www.sitename.com/my-account*

I tried using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^page/?$ myaccount/my-account.php  [NC,L]
```

But does't work.
What is wrong in this?

*Another easy way is to create a page and in that page just redirect to my account page. But I thought of doing through .htaccess*

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say you want to redirect from a subfolder to another subfolder but your code shows that you're redirecting from a subfolder to a php page and that php page doesn't exist in woocommerce's default structure (there is no valid /my-account.php but there is a /my-account).

If you're trying to redirect everything from /page to /myaccount just use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?page/(.*)$ my-account/$1 [R=301,L]
```

or is you want to do a simple redirect from just one subfolder to another, do this:

```
Redirect 301 /page /my-account
```

Comment: page is not a folder .its just a url

Comment: a URL contains folders and files. Your code is redirecting a folder to a file and you are wanting to redirect a folder to a folder. Either way, in my example I used myaccount/ and it should have read my-account/ because that is the correct name of the folder in the URL and I mistyped it. I've updated my answer.